# Vue-bootstrap nav link to 'external application'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vue-component, navbar

I have an application I decide to use `vue-bootstrap` over just `bootstrap` for the added features like *tabs*. Since I already have `vue-bootstrap` in the project, I decided to also rewrite the nav into it. Right now I have a problem where the links in the navigation point to the correct URL, however when I click them, nothing happens. I suspect Vue internally takes control over the request to follow the link.

I have the following code in Latte templating language:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
        <div>
            <b-nav n:if="$menu->hasVisibleItemsOnMenu()">
                {foreach $menu->getVisibleItemsOnMenu() as $itemsParent}
                    {if $itemsParent->hasVisibleItemsOnMenu() === false}
                        <b-nav-item n:attr="active => $itemsParent->isActive()">
                            <a href="{$itemsParent->getRealLink()}">{$itemsParent->getRealTitle()}</a>
                        </b-nav-item>
                    {else}
                        <b-nav-item-dropdown
                                text="{$itemsParent->getRealTitle()}"
                                extra-toggle-classes="nav-link-custom"
                                right
                        >
                            {foreach $itemsParent->getVisibleItemsOnMenu() as $item}
                                <b-dropdown-item n:attr="active => $item->isActive()" >
                                    <a href="{$item->getRealLink()}">{$item->getRealTitle()}</a>
                                </b-dropdown-item>
                            {/foreach}
                        </b-nav-item-dropdown>
                    {/if}
                {/foreach}
            </b-nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The link in the dropdown should redirect me to the page/URL in the link. Right now, nothing happens.

- Vue set up
  in `<head>`

```html
  <!-- Load required Bootstrap and BootstrapVue CSS -->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css"/>

  <!-- Load polyfills to support older browsers -->
  <script src="//polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CMutationObserver" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Load Vue followed by BootstrapVue -->
  <script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
```

in footer

```
  <script>
    window.app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
    })
  </script>
```

Comment: Can you provide your code, URL?

Comment: Code is right here, what else do you need? The link generated I click is `http://localhost:8080/league.front/`

Comment: Do you get some console errors, how did you change the component (node_modules folder, etc)? I'm trying to reproduce

Comment: No console errors, vue-bootstrap set up added to question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I get it. The `<b-nav-item>` component has a [`href` property](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/nav#comp-ref-b-nav-item). Inserting your code inside it, it works.

So I remove all the conditionals and just cloned the items.

```js
window.app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

  <title>My first BootstrapVue app</title>

  <!-- Required Stylesheets -->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

  <!-- Required scripts -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-polyfill@latest/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Our application root element -->
  <div id="app">
    <b-container>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
        <div>
          <b-nav n:if="$menu->hasVisibleItemsOnMenu()">


            <b-nav-item href="https://google.com" n:attr="active => $itemsParent->isActive()">
              Google
            </b-nav-item>

            <b-nav-item href="https://bing.com" n:attr="active => $itemsParent->isActive()">
              Bing
            </b-nav-item>
            <b-nav-item href="https://yahoo.com" n:attr="active => $itemsParent->isActive()">
              Yahoo
            </b-nav-item>
            <b-nav-item-dropdown text="Dropdown" extra-toggle-classes="nav-link-custom" right>

              <b-dropdown-item href="https://google.com" n:attr="active => $item->isActive()">
                Google
              </b-dropdown-item>
              <b-dropdown-item href="https://bing.com" n:attr="active => $item->isActive()">
                Bing
              </b-dropdown-item>
              <b-dropdown-item href="https://yahoo.com" n:attr="active => $item->isActive()">
                Yahoo
              </b-dropdown-item>
            </b-nav-item-dropdown>

          </b-nav>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </b-container>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

There is an extra `</div>` in your code, I don't think that was interfering.

It's hard to say without the correct CSS, but the links seems to be working.

Comment: It works! You even don't have to have the `a` tag inside afterward.